# Simple Python script for mass email optout

Tags: python, django

I have a Python script that opts a user out of emails.

```
optouts = [
"user1@example.com",
"user2@example.com",
"user3@example.com",
]

for email in optouts:
    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    profile = user
    profile.allow_mass_mails = False
    profile.save()
    print email, "opted out."


print "done."
```

There are about 10,000 emails that are being opted out. However, whenever it finds an email that is tied to a deleted account, it says:

> django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

I want it to say "skipped" (like it prints done) if the user profile doesn't exist.

I tried adding "else print "skipped" but that didn't work. i'm new to Python and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the exception and skip the record using [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue). Either by using the exception on the model object itself, `User.DoesNotExist`:

```
for email in optouts:
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        print email, "skipped."
        continue
    profile = user
    profile.allow_mass_mails = False
    profile.save()
    print email, "opted out."
```

Or by explicitly importing the base exception, [`django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist-and-doesnotexist):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

for email in optouts:
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print email, "skipped."
        continue
    profile = user
    profile.allow_mass_mails = False
    profile.save()
    print email, "opted out."
```

Comment: I know that's right! Now I'm getting the error: NameError: name 'django' is not defined.

Comment: @StevensonPrescott This means you have to import the `DoesNotExist` exception class properly. Seems you don't even import `django` here. How do the imports look like in this file?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User    (Then on a new line:) 
from company.models import UserProfile

Comment: @StevensonPrescott Updated to reflect your imports.

Comment: Now I'm getting: ImportError: cannot import name DoesNotExist

Comment: @StevensonPrescott Seems there's a little magic behind this exception, it's not defined in the said module, but rather on the models objects themselves. Updated with two ways how it should be possible to catch it.

Comment: That's awesome! I used the except ObjectDoesNotExist: method and it worked like a charm. Much Appreciated!